# Configure interceptor (proxy) on intercepted method

Tags: java, spring, aop

As far as I know, in Spring AOP when we want some method call to be intercepted, we configure an Aspect having such a pointcut configuration that matches wanted method invocation. In other words, we configure interception on the Aspect side.

Is there a way to configure it entirely from the opposite side, that is, on method which invocation is to be intercepted? I expect that something like this is possible:

```
@Component
class MyClass {
    @Intercept(interctptor="myInterceptor", method="invoke")
    Object methodThatWillBeIntercepted(Object arg) {
        // ..
    }
}

@Component(value="myInterceptor")
class MyInterceptor {
   Object invoke(MethodInvocation mi) {
      // ...
      if (someCondition) {
         return mi.proceed();
      } else {
         return someOtherValue;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, at least if you're using it with AspectJ. You can use the syntax `@annotation(com.mycompany.MyAnnotation)` in your pointcut declaration to target elements that are annotated with your annotation. You can read more about it in [section 9.2.3 of the Spring reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)

If you're not using AspectJ, but a generic proxy based interceptor, a "brute force" approact would be to proxy all the object you want to check and then check the method invocation argument to see if the method is annotated with your annotation, something like this:

```
class MyInterceptor {
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation mi) {
        if(mi.getMethod().getAnnotation(MyAnnotationClass.class) != null) {
            // Do the interception
        }
        else {
            return mi.proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't remember the exact API for MethodInvocation, but something like that.

Comment: Thanks NilsH. Could you plz clarify (probably with an example) what do you mean by “brute force” approach.

Comment: Then one more question — how to proxify some bean to “redirect” a call to MyInterceptor? I know that it's possible with the ProxyFactoryBean, but it can only be configured with an XML (I'd prefer annotations), or am I wrong?

Comment: If you're using Java Configuration with annotations, you can simply create the `ProxyFactoryBean` programatically.